# Why socket send only 1KB (425B) of data?

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, fileoutputstream

I am learning sockets and now I want to write file transfer program. I have server part and client part. Server part contains 2 ports: 5000 (commands) and 5001 (files). Now I want to send a file via socket and when I did something is wrong because only 425B of data is sending.

Here is client send method:

```
private void sendFile(Socket socket) {
    File file2 = new File("C:\\Users\\barte\\Desktop\\dos.png");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];
    System.out.println(file2.exists());
    try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file2);
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStream secondOutput = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\barte\\Desktop\\received\\dos.png")) {
        int count;
        while ((count = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, count);
            secondOutput.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see (image below) I am writing this file also locally and everything is ok, all of 73KB of data is writed.

Now, on server side I am trying to receive this file:

```
case SEND: {
   new Thread(() -> {
     printWriter.println("Server is receiving files right now...");
     try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5001)) {
       while (true) {
        new FilesTransfer(serverSocket.accept()).start();
       }
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }).start();
     break;
   }
```

And inside FilesTransfer run method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello there");
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = inSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\barte\\Desktop\\received\\file");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = inputStream.read()) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        inSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where is a bug? Why only empty bytes are sending when locally everything it's fine?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```java
while ((count = inputStream.read()) > 0) {
```

Your code uses [`InputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read()), which reads individual bytes (or `-1` when end-of-stream). Right now, you are reading individual bytes, interpreting that as a length, and then writing that number of 0x00 bytes from `bytes` to the file. This stops when you read a 0x00 byte from the stream.

You need to change this to use [`InputStream.read(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)):

```java
while ((count = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
```

That is, you need to pass `bytes` in, and check for the result being unequal to `-1`, not if it is greater than zero (`0`), although `read(byte[])` will only return `0` if the passed in byte array has length zero, so that is not a real concern.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in this way:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello there");
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = inSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\barte\\Desktop\\received\\file");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];
        int byteRead= 1;
        while (byteRead > -1) {
            byteRead= inputStream.read();
            outputStream.write(byteRead);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        inSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Actually END OF FILE or EOF means -1 and you did > 0 so 0 was taken and it stopped the connection saving the file.

I also recommend to write a logic to transfer the filename as a command to the server so that the file is saved with the correct name and extension!

Comment: wow thank you man, that helps me, so now byte[]bytes is not needed right? Also I will implement logic for names and extensions, but should i do it on 5000 port (like text commands) or send in file port?

Comment: I would recommend to do it on the port used for commands : do the following: Send a request from client about file and data about file and a upload command along with authorization(if you want security). Then you send a confirmation from server. Then send the file data from the other port!